# Converting a Dictionary in MySql 8

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, dictionary

I have a JSON structure stored in a MySql table.  Now, months later, I have a requirement to join to pieces found deep in the bowels of this JSON string.

```
{
    "id": "000689ba-9891-4d82-ad13-a7b96dc08ec4",
    "type": "emp", 
    "firstName": "Brooke", 
    "facilities": {
        ​​​​​"0001": [{​​​​​
            "id": 1, 
            "code": "125", 
            "name": "DSL", 
            "type": "MGMTSupport", 
            "payRate": 18}​​​​​], 
        "0002": [
        {
            ​​​​​"id": 1, 
            "code": "100", 
            "name": "Server", 
            "type": "FOH", 
            "payRate": 8
        }, {
            ​​​​​"id": 2, 
            "code": "320", 
            "name": "NCFOHTrainer", 
            "type": "NCHourlyTraining", 
            "payRate": 14.5
        }​​​]
    },
    "permissions": ["read:availability", "..."], 
    "primaryJobCode": "150", 
    "primaryPayRate": 9, 
    "primaryFacility": "0260"
}​
```

​​​​The big question is: How do I shape this as a query in MySql when the facilities do not follow a single key/value pattern?  i.e.: the key to the first entry *is* the facilityId so I cannot use a path like '$.0001' and the dictionary value is an array so how do I path that correctly?

```
select id        as EmployeeId
     , companyId as cpkEmployeeId
     , json_table( `data`
                 , '$.facilities[*]' COLUMNS( facilityId VARCHAR(10) PATH '$.????'
                                            , NESTED PATH '??? $[*] ???' COLUMNS ( code VARCHAR(10) PATH '$.code'
                                                                                 , payRate DECIMAL(8,4) PATH '$.payRate') facilities
  from employee
;
```

Yea - the above does not work.  Any help appreciated.

---

Desired output?

[Other columns from the table] plus facilityId, code & payrate.

A single row in the native table could produce something like:

```
   id   | companyId | facilityId | code | payRate
--------+-----------+------------+------+---------
   1    |  324337   |    0001    |  125 | 18.0000
   1    |  324337   |    0002    |  100 |  8.0000
   1    |  324337   |    0002    |  320 | 14.5000
```

Comment: Problematic JSON. `code` and `payRate` are attributes but `facilityId` is attribute name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
WITH
cte AS (
SELECT test.id,
       test.value,
       jsontable.facilityId,
       CONCAT('$.facilities."', jsontable.facilityId, '"') path
FROM test
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(JSON_KEYS(test.value, '$.facilities'),
                      '$[*]' COLUMNS (facilityId CHAR(4) PATH '$')) jsontable
)
SELECT cte.id,
       cte.facilityId,
       jsontable.code,
       jsontable.payRate
FROM cte
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(JSON_EXTRACT(cte.value, cte.path),
                      '$[*]' COLUMNS (code CHAR(3) PATH '$.code',
                                      payRate DECIMAL(6, 4) PATH '$.payRate')) jsontable
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=18ab7b6f181b61fb53f88a6de6e049be

Comment: Thank you.  I learned a lot from that example and was able to apply it!